# Minitest stub passing block to mock instance

Tags: ruby, minitest

I stumbled across a curious behaviour and haven't been able to figure out what I was doing wrong. I hope somebody can enlighten me.

I was trying to stub the Redis client during my tests in a Rails application. Therefore I was using the [MockRedis](https://github.com/brigade/mock_redis) gem. I have created a `RedisFactory` class with the single class method `.create`, which I wanted to stub with an optional `MockRedis` instance like so:

```
def stub_redis(mock_redis = MockRedis.new)
    RedisFactory.stub :create, mock_redis { yield }
end
```

This did not work and always threw a `ArgumentError in Foo#Bar wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`. Some further debugging revealed that a call of `RedisFactory.create 'foo'` within the `stub`-block resulted in an error that `'foo' is no method on instance of MockRedis::Database`.

However, I have been able to solve this problem with the following code snippet, using a lambda function to *catch* the incoming arguments:

```
def stub_redis(mock_redis = MockRedis.new)
    RedisFactory.stub(:create, ->(*_args) { mock_redis }) { yield }
end
```

Could anybody explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now MiniTest tries to guess if the passed `val_or_callable` is a `Proc` by checking whether it responds to `call`, cf.:

- https://apidock.com/ruby/Proc/call
- https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/b84b8176930bacb4d70d6bef476b1ea0f7c94977/lib/minitest/mock.rb#L226

Unfortunately, in this specific case `Redis` as well as the passed `MockRedis`-instance both provide a generic `call`-method for executing Redis commands, cf.:

- https://github.com/brigade/mock_redis/blob/master/lib/mock_redis.rb#L51

You already found the correct workaround. In this case, your only chance is to explicitly use the proc-version of `stub`.

*Note:* There are some communities using `def call` as a pattern with [ServiceObjects](https://hackernoon.com/the-3-tenets-of-service-objects-c936b891b3c2) in Ruby which may have a difficult time using minitest's `stub`. It is probably a good idea to open an issue in [seattlerb/minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest).